# MooTools request url returns 404 errorpage

Tags: url, mootools, request, http-status-code-404

I am having trouble because my MooTools AJAX request doesn't find my PHP script URL request. First I have an index.php which loads in ControllerList.php (List files and delete each one), then in that script, I have this MooTools script for calling controllerDelete.

There is the problem because It says:

```
404: The requested URL /Files/ControladorDelete.php was not found on this server.
```

This is the structure of my project:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/imagen1nvj.png/

This is my MooTools script:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

  $$('a.div').addEvent('click', function(e) {

    e.stop();
    var id_file = this.get('id');
    var new = id_file.split('#');  

    var DeleteFile = new Request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'ControllerDelete.php?id_file='+new[1]+'&name='+new[0], ERROR 
      onRequest: function() {},
      onSuccess: function() {
      },
      onFailure: function(){alert('Error!');}
    }).send();

  });
});
```

The request keeps giving me error. Thanks for your help

I already changed to URL: Controler/ControllerDelete.php but Its the same and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One look at your folder tree tells me that you need to form your URL like this:

```
url: 'Source%20Files/Controller/ControllerDelete.php?id_file='+new[1]+'&name='+new[0],
```

To fix your error.